# Is this good idea to save data like json in Preference?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

In my android app I load some data (`JSON`) from wed server. And I need to store that data. 
 
All data, which I want to save - it is fixed number (for ex. 5) of `JSONObject`s with 30-50 fields.

Is this good idea to save each `JSONObject` in `Preference`? Or will be better to use `SQLite`?

note: why I ask?

- save in `Preference` - implementation take 10 minutes.
- use `SQLite` - implementation take one or two days, and required to
  edit database, when I will add new fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer database, and if you need 2 whole days for a reasonably simple database setup, you should perhaps take any chance to practice with it.

However, if you're sure you're never going to have any advantage of (complexer) queries, then saving it into a database might not give you any real advantages.

Comment: About using - I will not use any sql requests to database (only store date). About implementation - 5*50 = 250 fields. 2 days - ofcource I got a little excited, but it requires attention.

Comment: Why store, if you wont request.

Comment: what is the point of storing, if you will not request the date ?

Comment: You could also store the entire json to one field in the db. also a "10 minute implementation"

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer sharedpreference here , because size of data is not too big. If size of data was too big and had many fields then database would be first choice. You can save the whole json String into preference and use it after parsing at run time.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation choice would be a database table that stores the object as something you can then transform into a native intermediate object. By keeping the local data stored as JSON you're potentially locking yourself into keeping a JSON parser within the app for the foreseeable future even if your web service changes its format.

For example, if your web service changes to XML you're still going to have to keep the JSON parser in the app to handle those users who upgrade the app and have to do a data migration.

Answer (score 0):

You could save JSON directly in SQLite database. If you parse data and then save in database then it would take some time for you to make everything work. But think about saving JSON directly in database. It will require two fields only in database link and json response.

Advantages:
- Big time saving 
- You could save the same solution in your future apps for saving JSON in database.

Disadvantages
- You will not be able to query data 
- You will have to parse every-time